# Using CSV .txt files with arrays in VB.NET to edit data?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv, text-files

I'm a beginner trying to learn VB.NET and I'm not quite sure how I'll explain this, but I'll give it a shot. Basically, I've written a txt file with about 10 lines of data in CSV form.

For example:

```
John, 10, 14
Michael, 14, 27
Billy, 13, 45 
etc, etc....
```

I just want to be able to read and edit particular lines - not necessarily add new lines.

Just wondering if someone could just outline how I'd go about this - not asking anyone to write the program for me. I just don't know what to do and I couldn't understand other answers I've found on SO that attempted to solve the same problem. I don't know if I'm just a bit dense or something so it'd be great if someone could perhaps give a simple, 'dumbed-down' outline of what I need to do.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to load all the data in memory (array/list/class) edit the data and save it all in the file. Don't see it as modifying one line in a file. See it as loading/editing/saving. Start by figuring out how to read the data, then store the data, then edit, save. If you have specific problem you can come back and ask.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Just wondering what you mean by (array/list/class) ?

Comment: You need to store the data somewhere. This can be in a combination (or/and) of array/list/class.

Comment: @BillyMcNab You'll want to have a look at the textfieldparser class in vb: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

as stated in the comments you usually read all the file into memory, manipulate it and write it all back.

dotnet has a method that puts a file content in an array (line by line)

if you need to access individual cells in the CSV you probably want to run the split method on each line and join to merge them back together.

the split/join methods are either an method of the string/array object or its in the [Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/System.String%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace

a method for writing the file back is also in the [System.IO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Namespace

Answer (score 0):

You don't asking to write the code for you, I can understand you but I think there is no way to show how can you do that. I used split/join methods as @weberik mentioned. It is a simple console application:

```
Public Class Sample

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        CreateExampleFileIfNotExists()
        'lines variable is an "Array"
        Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("Example.txt")
        'write items to the console
        ShowItems(lines, "Values before edit:")
        'edit the items
        EditItems(lines)
        'write edited items to the console
        ShowItems(lines, "Values after edit:")
        'save changes?
        Save(lines)
        'finish
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub ShowItems(lines() As String, header As String)
        Console.WriteLine(header)
        Dim headers() As String = {"Name:", "Value1:", "Value2:"}
        WriteItems(headers)
        For Each line In lines
            WriteItems(line.Split(","))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub EditItems(lines() As String)
        For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Length - 1
            Dim line As String = lines(i)
            Dim values() As String = line.Split(",")
            'edit the item
            values(0) = "Edited " & values(0)
            values(1) += i
            values(2) *= i
            lines(i) = String.Join(",", values)
        Next
        Console.WriteLine() 'empty line
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub WriteItems(itemValues() As String)
        Dim line As String = ""
        For Each item In itemValues
            line &= item & vbTab & vbTab
        Next
        Console.WriteLine(line)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub CreateExampleFileIfNotExists()
        If Not IO.File.Exists("Example.txt") Then
            IO.File.WriteAllLines("Example.txt", {"John,10,14", "Michael,14,27", "Billy,13,45"})
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub Save(lines() As String)
        Console.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "Do you want to save the changes? Y/N")
        Dim result = Console.ReadKey()
        Console.WriteLine()
        Select Case result.Key
            Case ConsoleKey.Y
                IO.File.WriteAllLines("Example.txt", lines)
                Console.WriteLine("The changes has been saved.")
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how do I try out this code?? Do I need to put buttons or text-boxes on the form?  It doesn't work when I try to run it..

Comment: It is a console application. So, the code cannot run properly with a windows application by default. To run this code create a new project with choosing "Console Application" and delete "Module1.vb" file. After that add a new class with name "Sample" and fill your class with above code.

Comment: Thanks a million again, but I have just one question: I did what you said and I still get the following error message.   Error 1 'Sub Main' was not found in 'ConsoleApplicationTest.Module1'. ??

Comment: Did you delete the "Module1.vb" file in your project as I said?

Comment: Hmm, ok. So, right click on project in solution explorer click properties, choose "Sample" class as "Startup object" in the opened window. see http://i.imgur.com/QDZ9Akb.png